# Hasura table relationship

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I'm new to hasura and i'm searching how to relate a table with a column of int of array to another table.

Let's say Users table is:
[image]

..and Products table is:
[image]

I want to return

products {
id

name

number of users

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a `user_products` table. Hasura is meant to track relations in a relational database. Your schema is not the way a many-to-many relationship  is accomplished. Have a look at [Hasura's docs](https://hasura.io/learn/database/postgresql/core-concepts/6-postgresql-relationships/#many-to-many) for a clear explanation although this is more of a general relational database concept than strictly a Hasura thing.

If you absolutely *must* use this schema, you can make a [View](https://hasura.io/learn/database/postgresql/views/) and track it in Hasura. In your View, you can [UNNEST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html) `product_ids` (which will make a unique row for each `id,product_id` pair) and make the correct many-to-many relationships which you can then aggregate in hasura. This is not at all advisable.